# Jack does not see soundcard inputs

Tags: soundcard, jack, audio-recording

I am trying to record my guitar via an usb-soundcard (umc404), but Jack does not seem to know any inputs of my soundcard. I am using the UI of Ardour5 for starting Jack.

```
@Linux-PC:~$ jack_lsp
system:capture_1
system:capture_2
system:capture_3
system:capture_4
system:playback_1
system:playback_2
system:playback_3
system:playback_4
```

ALSA seems to recognize them (?):

```
Linux-PC:~$ amixer -c2
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Front Left: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Rear Left: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
  Rear Right: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',1
  Capabilities: cvolume cvolume-joined cswitch cswitch-joined
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: Capture 0 - 127
  Mono: Capture 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'UMC404HD 192k Internal Clock Validity',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [on]
Simple mixer control 'UMC404HD 192k Output',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 119 [94%] [-8.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 119 [94%] [-8.00dB] [on]
  Rear Left: Playback 119 [94%] [-8.00dB] [on]
  Rear Right: Playback 119 [94%] [-8.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'UMC404HD 192k Output',1
  Capabilities: pvolume pvolume-joined pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Limits: Playback 0 - 127
  Mono: Playback 127 [100%] [0.00dB] [on]
```

How do I get Jack to see them?

Comment: how do you start jack atm? i often tried to start jackd from the commandline until i got the right combination. For my onboard it is: "/usr/bin/jackd -d alsa -d hw:PCH". And for my usb-audio card it is: "/usr/bin/jackd -d alsa -p 256 -d hw:Pro" (M-Audio FastTrack Pro) The identifiers can be found with aplay -l

Comment: I startet Jack via the UI from Ardour, with alsa as driver and my soundcard as hw

Comment: If you are running `pulseaudio` in parallel, you should first disable the sound card in `pavucontrol`.  Otherwise, jack won't see the device as it is already occupied by PA.

Comment: I recommend that you try to start JACK before starting ardour in the command line, to see what blocks it from starting. Or are there any error messages in ardour? Also, please add to the question above, that you are starting jack from ardour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @ridgy commented above, I had to disable pulseaudio first. I used `pulseaudio -k`, there may be more elegant ways, but it works now :).